# Vaadin and Atmosphere on WildFly 13

Tags: websocket, vaadin, wildfly, atmosphere

will provide a brief description of the problem
Currently running a J2EE application on JBOSS 6.1.0 on Java 7.
Application UI is developed on VAADIN 6 and also has Atmposphere framework.
Need to upgrade to JAVA 8. For that i had to also upggrade from JBOSS 6 to WildFly 13.
Everything works fine except for the following problem
Application starts and deploys with out any errors.
I go to the Login page.
Login successfully and go to the Application home page.
No errors so far
After 1-2 seconds i get on the WildFly console the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000010: Session is invalid q2gXNR6KftYiyRJD6LZlJc-COtHWVr4ol3EtMuOy
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.invokeRunnable(ServletContextImpl.java:1029)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl.onAsyncComplete(AsyncContextImpl.java:604)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl.access$100(AsyncContextImpl.java:71)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl$3.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:319)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl$6.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:481)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl$TaskDispatchRunnable.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:594)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000010: Session is invalid q2gXNR6KftYiyRJD6LZlJc-COtHWVr4ol3EtMuOy
    at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.getAttribute(InMemorySessionManager.java:512)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.getAttribute(HttpSessionImpl.java:122)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl.checkBeanIdentifierIndexConsistency(HttpSessionContextImpl.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl.associate(HttpSessionContextImpl.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl.associate(HttpSessionContextImpl.java:25)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle.requestInitialized(HttpContextLifecycle.java:244)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldInitialListener.requestInitialized(WeldInitialListener.java:152)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.requestInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:246)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl.setupRequestContext(AsyncContextImpl.java:696)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl.access$700(AsyncContextImpl.java:71)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl$7.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:609)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl$2.call(ServletContextImpl.java:181)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl$2.call(ServletContextImpl.java:178)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.invokeRunnable(ServletContextImpl.java:1027)
    ... 10 more**
```

After that exception whatever click i do on the application it does not work.
Is this problem related to Wildfly 13 and Atmosphere ?

I am using VAADIN 6.8.12 and Atmoshphere 1.0.9
Here is my web.xml related configuration

```
<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.disableOnStateEvent</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.HeaderBroadcasterCache</param-value>  <!-- HeaderBroadcasterCache  UUIDBroadcasterCache -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.maxIdleTime</param-name>
      <param-value>300000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.CometSupport.maxInactiveActivity</param-name>
      <param-value>300000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>**org.vaadin.dontpush.server.DontPushOzoneServlet**</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <description>Vaadin application class to start</description>
      <param-name>application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.gnt.iglbf.ui.operator.IglbfoperatorApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <description>Application widgetset</description>
      <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
      <param-value>com.gnt.vaadin.application.widgetset.IglbfoperatorWidgetset</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>      
      <param-name>connectionGuardTimeout</param-name>
      <param-value>60</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UIDL/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And below you can also see tho pom.xml of the UI Module of the Application. I have removed some irrelevant dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-jbossweb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-tomcat7</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-poll</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>dontpush-addon-ozonelayer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>stepper</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>switch</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.12</version>
```

Finally below i pasted relevant JBOSS console out with some warnings as well that i unfortunately cannot really undertsand. Me not very savvy on VAADIN and Atmosphere, the application was not developed by myself that why i am having lack of knowledge on Web sockets and JBOSS as well

```
    2018-07-13 11:56:40,452 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Installed AtmosphereHandler AtmosphereGwtAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path: /UIDL
2018-07-13 11:56:40,483 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
2018-07-13 11:56:40,920 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
2018-07-13 11:56:40,920 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport running under container: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) - 2.0.9.Final using javax.servlet/3.0
2018-07-13 11:56:40,935 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Installed Default AtmosphereInterceptor [Android Interceptor Support, SSE Interceptor Support, JSONP Interceptor Support]. Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults in your xml to disable them.
2018-07-13 11:56:40,935 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.HeaderBroadcasterCache
2018-07-13 11:56:40,935 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Neither TrackMessageSizeInterceptor or TrackMessageSizeFilter are installed. atmosphere.js may receive glued and incomplete message.
2018-07-13 11:56:40,951 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) HttpSession supported: false
2018-07-13 11:56:40,951 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
2018-07-13 11:56:40,951 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
2018-07-13 11:56:40,951 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Using Broadcaster: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
2018-07-13 11:56:40,951 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Atmosphere Framework 1.0.9 started.
```

And heres console out after i login , receive the error and then try to click to any link and on the console this is what i get

```
    2018-07-13 12:03:36,534 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Servlet] (default task-4) WELD-000714: HttpContextLifecycle guard leak detected. The Servlet container is not fully compliant. The value was 1
2018-07-13 12:03:36,534 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Context] (default task-4) WELD-000225: Bean store leak detected during org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpRequestContextImpl association: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /IGLBFOperator/UIDL/null ]
2018-07-13 12:03:36,534 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Context] (default task-4) WELD-000225: Bean store leak detected during org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl association: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /IGLBFOperator/UIDL/null ]
2018-07-13 12:03:36,550 INFO  [org.vaadin.dontpush.server.AtmosphereDontPushHandler] (default task-4) Failed to find resource for [1]
2018-07-13 12:03:36,659 INFO  [org.vaadin.dontpush.server.AtmosphereDontPushHandler] (default task-4) Failed to find resource for [1]
2018-07-13 12:03:37,537 INFO  [org.vaadin.dontpush.server.AtmosphereDontPushHandler] (default task-4) You have set an infinite timeout for your comet connection this is not recommended
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated. Shouldn't be something complex its just i don't know much on Atmosphere and VAADIN. 
On JBOSS 6.1.0 with JAVA 7 all the above configuration works fine

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your specific question, but I'm also in the middle of upgrading a web app that ran on wildfly 8, and moving to wildfly 13. I've found the issue to be many of the dependencies and version conflict resolution. We had atmosphere in our app as well, and I upgraded to the latest atmosphere-runtime 2.4.30. Not sure if your VAADIN component, which looks like it relies on atmosphere will work with the latest, but I figured I'd mention that. Also, wildfly 13 has a lot of dependencies pre-packaged in the modules sub directory, but sometimes, those are too new for these older applications, so you'll either need to add additional items to those, or find your jboss-deployment-structure.xml in your app, and make necessary changes to the dependencies list in that file. 
Sorry I can't be of more help. Hope this at least helps some.

Edit: P.S. Upgrading an application server isn't usually the easiest thing, especially for more complex applications. I've been working on this wildfly 13 migration for over a week, and I've had to make many code changes, and there will be many more weeks before i'm done.